# React setState in class component not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Good day; I'm in need of assistance with the following problem:

A React class component (extending `React.Component`) exposes a method to set it's state on command. I know that using a prop on the component instead could probably solve this problem, but this public method is extremely helpful in my specific scenario and I'm not willing to give up on it just yet.

The method looks like this:

```
public setContent = (newDoc: IDocsEntry) => {
    console.log('Updating with', newDoc);
    this.setState(() => ({doc: newDoc}), () => console.log(this.state.doc));
  };
```

and I've also tried

```
public setContent = (newDoc: IDocsEntry) => {
    console.log('Updating with', doc);
    this.setState(() => ({newDoc: {id: doc.id, path: doc.path, title: doc.title, content: doc.content}}), () => console.log(this.state.doc));
  };
```

The issue is as following:

- on initially setting this state using this method, everything works as expected
- when I then close this component (it lives in a modal), do something else and then try to update the state using this method, it simply does not update

In my console logs, I can see that the method is called with the new and correct object, but the callback of `setState` simply shows the old state from the first invocation of this function.

**Edit:** file / class structure

```
interface Props {
  onClose: () => void
}
interface State {
  open: boolean,
  isEditor: boolean,
  doc: IDocsEntry
}
class ModalDocsFile extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  docPreEditing: IDocEntry | null = null;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      isEditor: false,
      doc: {
        id: -1,
        path: '',
        title: '',
        content: ''
      }
    };
  }

  public show = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({open: true}));
  };

  public setEditor = (edit: boolean, skipSave?: boolean) => {
    this.setState(() => ({isEditor: edit}));
    if (edit) this.docPreEditing = this.state.doc;
    if (edit === false && !skipSave) this.save(); // editor is closed -> save
    if (edit === false && skipSave) this.setState(state => ({doc: this.docPreEditing || state.doc})); // editor is closed without saving -> restore
  };

  public setContent = (newDoc: IDocsEntry) => {
    console.log('Updating with', newDoc);
    this.setState(state => ({...state, doc: newDoc}), () => console.log(this.state.doc));
  };

  private save = () => {
    if (this.state.doc.title === '') return;
    if (this.state.doc.id === -1) {
      // is new
      console.log('Saving new', this.state.doc);
      fetchPOST({
        url: 'https://api.crowbait.de/docs',
        auth: true,
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.doc)
      }).then(res => this.setState(state => ({doc: {...state.doc, id: parseInt(res as string)}})));
    } else {
      // update
      console.log('Updating', this.state.doc);
      fetchPOST({
        url: `https://api.crowbait.de/docs/${this.state.doc.id}`,
        auth: true,
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.doc)
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    // is viewer
    if (!this.state.isEditor) {
      return (
        <BasePageModal open={this.state.open} onClose={() => {
          this.setState(() => ({open: false}));
          this.props.onClose();
        }} height="80vh">
          <DocViewer doc={this.state.doc} onEdit={() => this.setEditor(true)} />
        </BasePageModal>
      );
    }

    // is editor
    return (
      <BasePageModal open={this.state.open} onClose={() => {
        if (this.state.isEditor) this.save();
        this.setState(() => ({open: false}));
        setTimeout(() => this.props.onClose(), 1000);
      }} height="80vh">
        <Grid container spacing={2} style={{height: '100%'}}>
          <Grid xs={6} style={{paddingRight: 32, height: '100%'}}>
            <TextField id="textfield-title" label="Title" value={this.state.doc.title}
              fullWidth size="small" style={{marginTop: 16, marginRight: 16}}
              onChange={e => this.setState(state => ({
                doc: {
                  ...state.doc,
                  title: e.target.value
                }
              }))}
              error={!this.state.doc.title} />
            <TextField id="textfield-path" label="Path" value={this.state.doc.path}
              fullWidth size="small" style={{marginTop: 8, marginRight: 16}}
              onChange={e => this.setState(state => ({
                doc: {
                  ...state.doc,
                  path: e.target.value
                }
              }))} />
            <TextField id="textfield-content" label="Content" value={this.state.doc.content}
              fullWidth size="small" multiline
              style={{marginTop: 16, marginRight: 16, height: '80%'}}
              inputProps={{style: {height: '100%', overflow: 'auto', fontFamily: 'monospace'}}}
              InputProps={{style: {height: '100%'}}}
              onChange={e => this.setState(state => ({
                doc: {
                  ...state.doc,
                  content: e.target.value.replaceAll('\r\n', '\n')
                }
              }))} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={6} style={{height: '100%'}}>
            <DocViewer doc={this.state.doc} isEditor onSave={() => this.setEditor(false)}
              onRevert={() => this.setEditor(false, true)} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </BasePageModal>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalDocsFile;
```

Comment: can you please share the entire code of the file , if possible?

Comment: @HarshSingla I've added the structure

Comment: did you try 'ComponetDidUpdate' lifecycle hook of React Component?

Comment: @HarshSingla since the state does not correctly update, that method (which is called after a state update) is of no use in this case. I've however tried logging the state in that method as well and there too it does not update.
It is as if the `this.setState(() => ...)` method is called always with the first version of the `newDoc` parameter the enclosing `setContent` method was called with initially...

Comment: In any case, the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, as it is so often, human error.

Another contributor to the project made changes, ignoring just enough of the project's contributing, code-review and linting guidelines to make this particular change somewhat unnoticed.

Another component calling this `setContent`-method also called another method in another component, which (via several intermediate steps and around even more corners) undid everything that `setContent` did.

So this was entirely our fault and not at all some issue in language mastery or React, but antipatterns and failed control mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

What does your constructor looks like, maybe you forgot to bind setContent

```
  this.setContent = this.setContent.bind(this);
```

Comment: I did not bind `this` in the constructor, true. But even without, why would it work the first time and not the second or third? All the other methods work flawlessly even without the binding as well... Anyway, I've tried binding it and it sadly does not make a difference.

Comment: I've also added the class structure (incl. constructor) to the post for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
public setContent = (newDoc: IDocsEntry) => {
    this.setState((prev) => { 
      //correct way to return and/or update state object
      return {...prev, doc: newDoc as IDocsEntry} 
    }
  };
```

or if your param name is newDoc:

```
public setContent = (newDoc: IDocsEntry) => {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      return {...prev, newDoc } 
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, sadly, it does not work... The first piece of code is semantically equivalent to my code and the second piece sadly does not solve the problem as well (it shouldn't behave differently from my code anyways).